# Angular2 - using 3rd parety module's component

Tags: angularjs, angular

I created a module which has a directive in it (`ObDatePickerModule`).
Also I created a project which has `ObDatePickerModule` in it's dependencies (under dependencies in `package.json`).
Next I am importing Module A in my project's module:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {ObDatePickerModule} from 'ng2-date-picker';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ObDatePickerModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Here is the app.component of the project:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ObDayPickerComponent} from 'ng2-date-picker';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<ob-day-picker [(ngModel)]="date"></ob-day-picker>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  entryComponents: [ObDayPickerComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  date = moment();
}
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
main.bundle.js:66421 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'ob-day-picker' is not a known element:
1. If 'ob-day-picker' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ob-day-picker' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<ob-day-picker [(ngModel)]="date"></ob-day-picker>
```

I checked that the component name is really `ob-day-picker`.

I have also consoled log both the module and the `ObDayPickerComponent` imports and it seems that the imports are correct.

What did I miss?

**Checkout the module repo:**
https://bitbucket.org/vlio20/ng2-date-picker

**The project can be found here:**
https://github.com/vlio20/3rd-ng2-module

Comment: I see no package with name `ng2-date-picker`. Check if `ObDatePickerModule` contains a declaration for `ObDayPickerComponent`.

Comment: @estus, where are you looking for it?

Comment: Where I would expect it to be, https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-date-picker . It is highly possible that the problem is with the package itself. Please, provide the link to source code in the question.

Comment: check it out - https://bitbucket.org/vlio20/ng2-date-picker

Comment: Is `ObDayPickerComponent` exported by `ObDatePickerModule`?

Comment: it is not exported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `ObDayPickerComponent` outside of `ObDatePickerModule` you have to export it like:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ObDayPickerComponent,
    ObCalendarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  exports: [ObDayPickerComponent], // this line
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class ObDatePickerModule {}
```

Comment: Now I an getting this error: `Unexpected value 'ObDatePickerModule' imported by the module`

Comment: Try to print `console.log(ObDatePickerModule);` front of `@NgModule` in your `app.module.ts` file

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: Here http://take.ms/BHyAc maybe it should be `./dist/app/app.module` and i am getting this error `Cannot read property disabled of undefined` because `pickerConfig` is undefined. I define it like `<ob-day-picker [(ngModel)]="date" [config]="{format:''}"></ob-day-picker>` and finally i've got this http://take.ms/C5um8

Comment: yes I changed it in my project as well, but I followed this: `https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/d80a6fc57f2f2121e5ad3c55199fb651eaa14c8f` and only when I added this line to my project (it is based on angular-cli) the issue was gone. In what project did you used http://take.ms/C5um8?

Comment: Fixed - the module was an dev-dependency I turned it to a dependency. Thanks a lot for the help!!!!

Comment: It's just my test project based on your ng2-date-picker package. I tried testing it

Comment: do you know if I can import the ts files of my library project? Without transpiling to js? Currently I see that there is an issue because of the annotations.